# How can I get XY Euler angles from a direction?

Tags: c#, c++, math, unity-game-engine

I have a first person camera controller implemented as follows:

```
float rotSpeed = 20.0f;

xRotation += deltaPos.y * rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
yRotation += deltaPos.x * -rotSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

while(xRotation > 360.0f) xRotation -= 360.0f;
while(xRotation < 0.0f)   xRotation += 360.0f;

while(yRotation > 360.0f) yRotation -= 360.0f;
while(yRotation < 0.0f)   yRotation += 360.0f;

cam.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, yRotation, 0);
```

I would like the camera to be able to snap to some target in 3D space.

If I use transform.LookAt(target), the camera controller will just snap the view right back where it came from, and I can't set xRotation and yRotation from the camera's rotation after the call to LookAt(), because LookAt() sometimes produces a Quaternion with a Z rotation.

So how can I find the X and Y rotation that would be required to point the camera at some target?

Comment: I wrote a few c# classes for angle conversions a few years ago.  They could do conversions between Spherical coordinates, roll/pitch/yaw, nutation/precession/rotation, or any arbitrary Euler angles.  I will see if I can find it.  This page was very helpful:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms

Answer (score 1):

You can easily modify the player's rotation with [Quaternion.LookRotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) and then interpolate it with [Quaternion.Lerp](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion.Lerp.html).

```
public Transform target;
float turnSpeed = 5.0f;

Quaternion lookAt = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, lookAt, Time.smoothDeltaTime * turnSpeed);
```

*Where transform is the player's transform.*

All you have to do from here is determine when the snapping rules should occur.

**Postscript:** That may not be all actually. If the target/player positions tend to move around a lot, you may experience a 'dead zone' in which the LookRotation won't get a solid snap onto it's target. More detail on this problem (and solutions) [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17313/how-to-prevent-homing-entities-from-orbiting-their-targets)

Comment: my problem is not smooth camera interpolation, its that I am rotating my camera to an exact pitch and yaw each frame. So I need to know how to update the stored pitch and yaw values if I suddenly change the camera's direction to look at a specific object.

Comment: You could always grab the euler angles of the lookAt Quaternion I suppose! [link](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Quaternion-eulerAngles.html)